# Constructing the path to the local resource

Tags: javascript, react-native

During the tests, I constructed a wall for pictures that was then used in the list of objects

const przyklad = require('../assets/servicesIcons/przyklad.png');

```
const product = 
[
  {
    id: 1, 
    image: przyklad,
    title: 'przyklad'
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    image: przykald2,
    title: 'przyklad2
  },
```

In Flatlista I downloaded objects and saw a list of pictures with the title. At the moment I wanted to change so that everything was downlad from the DB but the does not get me a picture, I do not know how to connect this string from the DB with require to read the picture?

```
function Product({id, image , title}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={styles.rootCointener}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.replace('Term', {id: id, title: title})}}>
                <Image style={styles.imageCointener} source={image} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.textCointener}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you add the data you are receiving from the DB as image in response?

Comment: How you receive image data from database. It's HTTL URL like `http://your-server.com/path/to/image.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `Base64` string from your DB for the image. You can use it as following

```
const base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64, <Your Base64 string>'
```

```
<Image style={styles.imageCointener} source={{uri: base64Image}}/>
```

***Note:*** Please comment / edit the quetion with what is the response ur getting from the `DB` So that I can assist better.